# Can get referenced dll's using the svn projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am beginner with SVN projects ( Working SVN with ASP.NET MVC3 c# ). I use ankhsvn in

my project.

[image]

I load my project in other pc with **File -> Open -> Subversion Project**

But i found some dlls are missing in the solution explorer.

**I explore project folders, there is some folders are without tick icon,**

**and some reference dlls are packages folder. this folder is with out the tick icon**

**Please see this images below.**

[image]

How can i solve this issue. Please Help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the reference path is different after downloading. You can define the correct path

Comment: Tick mark shows the files which are collected(synced) from the server! Check these libraries were already present on the server.